# How to get URL, which load balancer used to make the request to my application?

Tags: jetty

https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/10887

I know `jetty-server-9.4.50.v20221201` is end of life but I want to know if there is way. Does latest jetty provide a way? In `jetty-7.6.10.v20130312` it was working.

**Load balancer host name:** `lb-myapp.com`
**my app is deployed on:** `node1-myapp.com`, `node2-myapp.com`

How to get URL, which load balancer used to make the request to my application (ie `node1-myapp.com/myapi` or `node2-myapp.com/myapi`)?

In `jetty-7.6.10.v20130312` we used below method and it was returning `node1-myapp.com` or `node2-myapp.com`.

```
// request = org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request
String host = request.getConnection().getConnector().getHost();
```

In `jetty-server-9.4.50.v20221201` we are using below method but it return `ipaddress` of `node1-myapp.com` or `node2-myapp.com`.

```
// request = org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request
request.getLocalAddr()
```

We also tried but no luck

```
// baseRequest = org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request
log.trace("baseRequest.getOriginalURI(): " + baseRequest.getOriginalURI());

log.trace("baseRequest.getHttpURI().getHost(): " + baseRequest.getHttpURI().getHost());
log.trace("baseRequest.getHttpURI().getPort(): " + baseRequest.getHttpURI().getPort());

log.trace("baseRequest.getLocalName(): " + baseRequest.getLocalName());
log.trace("baseRequest.getLocalName(): " + baseRequest.getLocalName());
log.trace("baseRequest.getLocalAddr(): " + baseRequest.getLocalAddr());
log.trace("baseRequest.getLocalPort(): " + baseRequest.getLocalPort());

log.trace("baseRequest.getRemoteInetSocketAddress(): " + baseRequest.getRemoteInetSocketAddress());
log.trace("baseRequest.getRemoteAddr(): " + baseRequest.getRemoteAddr());
log.trace("baseRequest.getRemoteHost(): " + baseRequest.getRemoteHost());
log.trace("baseRequest.getRemotePort(): " + baseRequest.getRemotePort());

log.trace("baseRequest.getHeader(\"Host\"): " + baseRequest.getHeader("Host"));

log.trace("baseRequest.getHeader(\"X-Forwarded-Host\"): " + baseRequest.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Host"));

// request = javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
log.trace("request.getLocalAddr(): " + request.getLocalAddr());
log.trace("request.getLocalName(): " + request.getLocalName());
log.trace("request.getLocalPort(): " + request.getLocalPort());

log.trace("request.getRemoteAddr(): " + request.getRemoteAddr());
log.trace("request.getRemoteHost(): " + request.getRemoteHost());
log.trace("request.getRemotePort(): " + request.getRemotePort());

log.trace("request.getHeader(\"Host\"): " + request.getHeader("Host"));

log.trace("request.getHeader(\"X-Forwarded-Host\"): " + request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Host"));

log.trace("request.getRequestURI(): " + request.getRequestURI());
log.trace("request.getRequestURL(): " + request.getRequestURL());
```